# UI Testing Failure: Failed to update to requested orientation

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing

Sometimes under continuous integration there is an error (seem to be random error) like this:

> Test Assertion UI Testing Failure - failed: Failed to update to requested orientation.

[image]

While testing, device is rotated to the landscape mode and... it does not return back to the portrait mode. Why?

Do you know what may cause such Issue?

In code I have a lines:

```
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .landscapeLeft
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .portrait
```

It looks like related to the following part of code, but I do not know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: can check this by using PortraitUpsideDown instead of portrait?

Comment: How this would help?

Comment: actually i used this two line in my app ui test portion , it can  orient in landscape but can not in portrait mode. maybe there something probolem ... i also looking for it

Comment: Why do you think it will help?

Answer (score 1):

There is basically nothing to solve this is a Xcode 8 bug. When you get this error just rerun nothing else to do atm. I never had this issue on Xcode 7. What the error message is telling you is that it failed to get the requested orientation and your code lines is looking good:

```
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .landscapeLeft
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .portrait
```

Apple will hopefully solve this issue soon. You also could [report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) a bug to Apple too.